# Entity Framework Multiple Inheritance with several discriminators

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

I want to realize structure like this:

```
public enum TreeType {
    Product = 1,
    User = 2,
    Document = 3        
}

public enum ProductType {
    Service = 1,
    Ware = 2
}

public enum DocumentType {
    Order = 1,
    Invoice = 2
}

public abstract class Tree
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public TreeType Type { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Product : Tree
{
    [Required]
    public string Article { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }

    public Tree 
    {
        this.Type = TreeType.Product;
    }
}

public class User : Tree
{
    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public User 
    {
        this.Type = TreeType.User;
    }
}

public abstract class Document : Tree
{
    [Required]
    public int PageCount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

    public Document 
    {
        this.Type = TreeType.Document;
    }
}

public class Service : Product
{
    [Required]
    public int VisitCount { get; set; }

    public Service 
    {
        this.ProductType = ProductType.Service;
    }
}

public class Ware : Product
{
    [Required]
    public string StorageName { get; set; }

    public Ware 
    {
        this.ProductType = ProductType.Ware;
    }
}

public class Order : Document
{
    [Required]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public Order 
    {
        this.DocumentType = DocumentType.Order;
    }
}

public class Invoice : Document
{
    [Required]
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }

    public Invoice 
    {
        this.DocumentType = DocumentType.Invoice;
    }
}

public class TreeDbContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<Tree> Trees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>().ToTable("L_TREES");
            .Map<Product>(x => x.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)TreeType.Product)).ToTable("L_PRODUCTS");
            .Map<User>(x => x.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)TreeType.User)).ToTable("L_USERS");
            .Map<Document>(x => x.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)TreeType.Document)).ToTable("L_DOCUMENTS");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .Map<Service>(x => x.Requires("ProductType").HasValue((int)ProductType.Service)).ToTable("L_SERVICES");
            .Map<Ware>(x => x.Requires("ProductType").HasValue((int)ProductType.Ware)).ToTable("L_WARES");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .Map<Order>(x => x.Requires("ProductType").HasValue((int)DocumentType.Order)).ToTable("L_ORDERS");
            .Map<Invoice>(x => x.Requires("ProductType").HasValue((int)DocumentType.Invoice)).ToTable("L_INVOICES");    
    }
}
```

In database it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMgM7.png)

Two-level inheritance I can implement both through TPH, and through TPT, but multi-level inheritance, and even with several descriptors, I can not implement.

As an exit, I can use inheritance and combination, but the implementation is cumbersome and requires a lot of manual action to support in the future.

I tried to implement this architecture, but I did not succeed.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Have you considered not to use inheritance at all? This design will sandbag you forever. Do some reading on "composition over inheritance".

Comment: +1, while it probably can be done, this is certainly something that I don't recommend doing with an ORM, or any object model for that fact. Inheritance should strictly be used to enforce an "is a" relationship between classes. A "Service" is a  "Product"? A "Product" is a "Tree"? What is your objective with this "Tree" base class, or the inheritance in general?

Comment: So I share the logic. At each level, the entity has its own functional, which can be used in descendants. The code is used again. The minimum of the code.